# Cannot dismiss the Search view

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have a parent class with tableview and searchbar over it which is a subclass of tableview controller. Delegates for the searchBar and searchdisplaycontroller are set in a seperate class inherited from UISearchdisplaycontroller. The datasource and delegates for tableview and searchbar are handled in this class seperately. The classes are under ARC.

Hence, When a user taps on search, the control transfers from FilesListController (parent)class to this class. Now, When a user taps on cancel button, the searchbar delegate set in this class i.e.

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar
```

is CALLED but DOESN'T serve the purpose of dismissing the full screen searchtableview and return to the parentviewcontroller. However, if I don't write this delegate in the search class, it works properly. I have set the searchbar delegates in xib and on calling:

```
- (BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
```

like this:

```
self.searchResultsTableView.delegate = self;
self.searchResultsTableView.dataSource = self;
[parentFileViewController.searchDisplayController setDelegate:self];
```

Where am I going wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: [self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];

Comment: hey thanks @jussi .. it works!!! But why doesn't it dismiss by itself? This is like we are forcing the searchviewcontroller to dismiss.

Comment: because some want to store some Information before dissmissing the Controller. I will post this as an Answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to dismiss a UISearchBar with a SearchBarController, just use this Code:

```
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

you should implement resign the responder in the delegate function i.e

```
- (void)searchBarCancelButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *) searchBar {
      [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Comment: This simply dismisses the keyboard, but not dismiss the Search View and the cancel button.

Answer (score -1):

Memory warnings can appear at any time during the application run time, you must assume a memory warning will happen and the view and disposable objects will have to be recreated.

We are handling such situation by setting to nil our arrays:

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

if([self isViewLoaded] && self.view.window == nil)
{
    self.view = nil;
    keys = nil;
    names = nil;
    errorDuringNetworkCall = nil;
}
}
```

And by dismissing the search bar tableview before performing the segue operation:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"navigateToNextScreen" sender:self];
self.searchBar.text = @"";
[self.searchDisplayController setActive:NO animated:YES];
```

After a Memory warning is received the viewDidLoad method is called again and the arrays are populated, the search bar will continue to be useful.work without issues

Comment: I don't see this as answering the question at all